# Xcode 5 and localization of .xib files

Tags: localization, xib, xcode5, missing-features

I'm trying to localize a .xib file.

The problem: After clicking the "Localize button" in the inspector, I end up with a list containing "English" and nothing else, well this is normal. 
But usually, as I can remember there is a "+" button which lets you add a language to this list.

I've asked on apple developer forum, because I'm using a beta version, but the post has been removed (not sure why).

There's a workaround for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to add the localization in the project settings first.
Go to your project settings -> localizations -> + (plus button)

[image: How to add localization in XCode 5.0]

Comment: Note that Xcode 6 now uses "xliff" files that xcode will expect you to import/export, so you are no longer able to "add" raw localization files through this interface

Answer (score 18):

When talking about xcode 5, go Project settings and *make sure* that you have Project selected, not Target - focus on left upper corner. There was special column in previous version (see accepted answer) but now there is a kind of furtive list.

[image]

Once you select your Project, localization will appear under Info tab.